# pass paramter that is a url with parameters

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url, get

I'm using asp.net mvc

I have a url that have some parameters, one of them is a url
e.g
www.example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=url&p4=v4...

the url i want to add has few parameters. how can i add them to this url? becuase from the second parameter the first url take them

e.g
www.example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=www.example2.com?p21=v21&p22=v22&p23=v23&p4=v4...

p21,p22,p23 belongs to the second url (www.example2.com) but the first url (www.example.com) taking p22, p23 has it's own

p.s 
i can't control the first url process

Thank you all for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't control the first URL process"? Can you build the URL within your app or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`url encode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value of the query string parameter before sending it in the url:

```
http://www.example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=www.example2.com%3Fp21%3Dv21%26p22%3Dv22%26p23%3Dv23%26p4%3Dv4..
```

So in this example the value of the `p3` parameter is properly url encoded for transmission over the HTTP protocol and can be unambiguously decoded back to its original value of `www.example2.com?p21=v21&p22=v22&p23=v23&p4=v4` at the receiving site.

There are built-in methods in .NET for achieving this. For example the [`EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string urlEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString("www.example2.com?p21=v21&p22=v22&p23=v23&p4=v4");
// Will produce: www.example2.com%3Fp21%3Dv21%26p22%3Dv22%26p23%3Dv23%26p4%3Dv4
```

Of course if you are using the built-in helpers in ASP.NET MVC this url encoding will happen automatically.

If on the other hand you cannot control the building of this url then you will most definitely end up with an ambiguous and wrong url (like the one shown in your question) that no valid system will be able to understand. That's the reason why certain standards have been imposed.

Comment: It Works thank you.  from what i've read EscapeDataString only convert charcters to the hexdecimal value so why it's working? if i'm using my example without parameters meanning: www.example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=www.example2.com it works just fine too (it example2 does'nt require parameters)